# Elasticsearch geo queries

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-rest-client

We are migrating to ES and need to support different geo queries. 
We use a geo_point field type in our mapping. I can see that ES supports geo_bounding_box & geo_distance but I'm trying to figure out whether they can be used for our use cases below:

1.BBOX: where the box is defined using a central point & radius. As far as I understand, the geo_distance will create a circular shape, how can we use a bbox of that circle?

```
//something like this - but we want a box shape not circle
QueryBuilders.geoDistanceQuery("location")
            .point(lat, lon)
            .distance(r, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
```

2.LAT_WITHIN: how can we check for documents with latitude that is within a distance (north & south) from a central latitude?

```
//something like this - but with only lat & radius
QueryBuilders.geoDistanceQuery(pointField)
            .point(lat)   //only lat?
            .distance(r, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
```

3.LON_WITHIN: similarly to the above point but for longitude.

4.SAME POINT: find documents with the same lat & lon. So can we use here the geo point field in a term query or is it possible to use the lat/lon keys?

```
//point equal - this gives error
QueryBuilders.termQuery("location", "lat,lon");
//OR - this doesn't return
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("location.lat", lat))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("location.lon", lon));
```

using the first query gives error "Geo fields do not support exact searching, use dedicated geo queries instead: [location]". The second query doesn't return results.

Thanks

Comment: I think 1-2-3 and be achieve easily with the [`geo_polygon` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html). Regarding 4, you can use the `geo_distance` query with a very small radius.

Comment: thanks for your reply. From the code the geopolygon query builder expects a list of geopoints (three at least I guess). This might be a silly question but how can I  get a polygon from a lat and distance only?

Comment: This answer helped me. Thanks. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-geo-queries-java-api/173501/6